# Is there a way to debug a running JAR file on a live JVM?

Tags: java, jar, jvm

I am not sure if such a tool exists, so this may be moot.

Essentially, there is a JAR file containing a GUI program that is being executed in a JVM. I want to be able to see which interactions in the GUI trigger which lines of code in the source files. When I click a button on the GUI, I want to see exactly which method in the source code (or line of byte code) is triggered, and then see the flow of the program from there. I want to see values of variables, method calls, etc. Basically similar tools you would have if you were to use an IDE's debugger.

Also, decompiling the JAR and loading the source code into an IDE and using its debugger is not possible, since the JAR is launched with a Windows executable that passes in several arguments that I am unable to view. These arguments are critical to run the program.

Are there any existing tools that even come close to this?

Comment: But you can run the JAR standalone or you are able to extract the JAR from the .exe ? https://www.baeldung.com/java-application-remote-debugging

Comment: @PeterMmm No, basically the entire program is in its own JAR, but the JAR is launched from a separate .exe which is also responsible for setting up the JVM environment. The issue is I don't have a way to extract the exact parameters for launch from the .exe file. From what I can find in the source code, the String[] args in the JAR's main method takes in about 12 different parameters for launch, none of which I know. So basically I need to 'tap in' to the running JVM process that is initiated by the .exe and be able to 'see' the code running in real-time.

Comment: I think you are simply looking for "JVM remote debug"

Comment: @MatteoNNZ Is there a way to do that for a live JVM that I have no control over? Can I 'tap in' to an already-running Java process? I am not able to change the flags passed in to the JVM before launch. All of that is contained in the .exe file, which I do not have the source code for.

Comment: It is possible to do that with jdb (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdb.html). Though the debugging experience is much worse, best way would be to find the way the JVM is started and pass on the debug flags

Comment: That is a really good start, thanks. However, jdb does not seem to show the exact parameters used to launch the JAR, only the JVM. So I am able to set up the JVM properly, but I still am unable to launch the JAR since I do not know what to pass in to String[] args in the main method. Is there a log for the JVM that shows exactly how the JAR was launched?

Comment: Can be possible via environment JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS, but I don't know for sure: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/java.html#GUID-3B1CE181-CD30-4178-9602-230B800D4FAE. Depends heavily on how the JAR is executed and JVM version.